# Integrating google reCaptcha into an existing payment form

Tags: php, forms, captcha, recaptcha

recently my site has been receiving a lot of spam through my payments form and I've decided I need to add a `captcha` in order to prevent this.

I was looking at a few options and I decided to go with Googles `reCaptcha`. It seems easy enough to set up and use but I've been running into a few problems.

Firstly I've included this `script` in the header of the form:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

I've then included the actually `captcha` itself at the foot of the form:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdOVv4SAAAAAJ4muJvo_vD7vsd9T9QIfkEwcO7y"></div>
```

When I submit the form I do the following:

```
$captcha = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]; //Get Captcha token
$secret_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //Get Secret key
$google_response = http_get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", array("secret"=>$secret, "response"=>$captcha), $info); //perform Get request
print_r($info);
```

But nothing is happening, in fact the page which used to work just hangs and doesn't even display an error message. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? From my understanding of the documentation, the response will be in `JSON` and success will either be true or false, I'd like to continue with the payment if true or stop and return to the form if false.

any help is much appreciated. Or if anyone has an alternative solution to adding a captcha I'd be willing to look into that.

Answer (score 12):

Try this to run google new recaptcha 2015:

```
==PHP Verification==
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $userIP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $recaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $secretKey = "SECRET_KEY";
    $request = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secretKey}&response={$recaptchaResponse}&remoteip={$userIP}");

    if(!strstr($request, "true")){
        echo "NOPE (Failed Verification)";
    }
    else{
        echo "YUP (Successful Verification)";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty annoying that the response can't be parsed back into a PHP array or JSON object easily.

Comment: @NicholasPickering If you're using Composer, [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a nice package to do so.

Comment: Google itselfs recommends to only use POST-Requests for verification. Your method is vulnerable to users providing something like "token&secret=SecretOfAnotherRecaptchaAccount" as g-recaptcha-response if google doesn't block multiple secret-parameters.. This means users can verify with any valid recaptcha tokens, which is bad. Better use curl and a post request.

Answer (score 8):

**Don't use file_get_contents.** Google [recommends to use POST-Requests](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) to call their api. GET-Requests like above can result in multiple problems:

- it might be blocked to call on urls due to security (allow_url_fopen)
- a user might pass something like someToken&secret=otherSitesSecret as input to your $_POST[g-recaptcha-response]. If you simply string concat the called url, you will pass another secret to Google. Users can then verify themselves with any recaptcha response they got from any site. That is a security issue.
- the tokens that Google returns can be quite long. Webservers only support a few thousand characters in urls. This might lead to strings chopped off and you will receive an error for valid inputs.

Therefore, **use something like this**:

```
// Get resource
$curl = curl_init();

// Configure options, incl. post-variables to send.
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'secret' => 'your_secret_code_here',
        'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
    )
));

// Send request. Due to CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, this will return reply as string.
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

// Free resources.
curl_close($curl);

// Validate response
if(strpos($resp, '"success": true') !== FALSE) {
    echo "Verified.";
} else {
    echo "Not verified.";
}
```

Also, the validate part is more conservative in what it accepts as 'validated'.

Comment: as per [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354633/curl-recaptcha-not-working-php) you'll want to add `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0`in your array if you don't have SSL Certificate for the call (which I guess is not the most secure way of implementing a security feature !)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Google always uses valid certificates for their recaptcha api. Something is wrong on your system, if it does not validate. I also commented on the answer you linked, that there is really no need to do this.

Comment: Just for development purpose

Comment: (if you don't have ssl cert set