# cURL Recaptcha not working PHP

Tags: php, curl

**What I have**:

```
$data = array(
            'secret' => "my-app-secret",
            'response' => "the-response"
        );

$verify = curl_init();
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($verify);

var_dump($response);
```

**What I got**: `bool(false)` (which means the `curl_exec()` failed)

**What I expect**: a JSON object response

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the "http_build_query" is necessary in the post fields parameter. Mine works without it.

Comment: @danielson317 google accepts both `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format and `multipart/form-data` format, when you add http_build_query() here it gets converted from the 2nd (which is the default format when giving CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS an array) to the first, and with the $data provided by OP here costs 42 bytes of bandwidth encoded as the first, but 280 bytes of data encoded in the `multipart/form-data` format!  (multipart/form-data is much more space efficient for large and binary data, but for small data sets, the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format is much more space-efficient.)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Because you're attempting to connect via SSL, you need to adjust your cURL options to handle it. A quick fix to get this to work is if you add `curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false will make it so that it accepts any certificate given to it rather than verifying them.

```php
<?php

$data = array(
            'secret' => "my-secret",
            'response' => "my-response"
        );

$verify = curl_init();
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($verify);

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Please remove the SSL_VERIFYPEER=false thingy. Google always uses a valid certificate.

Comment: It used to work for me for over 2 years, without the extra line you propose (`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`) but today I was faced with the same problem as reported and by adding this line the problem went away.  So thanks for that.  But I really would like to understand where the problem lies now ?  Is this my server or is this Google ?  What cert is not verified now, by which party ?

Comment: If a google API is failing and setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false fixes the problem, try updating your CA certificates.

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST: 2`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER: 1`, `CURLOPT_CAINFO:$path_to_cert` where path_to_cert can be the cacert.pem file from https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem

Answer (score 8):

Here's an alternative method to cURL I found if it helps anyone.  Obviously input **$secret** and **$response** variables to pass it correctly.  Sorry the question is asking for a cURL solution, but this is the quickest method I've seen so I thought it would add it anyway because I know it will help somebody out there. :)

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$response);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
if($response["success"] === true){
    // actions if successful
}else{
    // actions if failed
}
```

Comment: cURL may be the only option if you have allow_url_fopen=0 in your PHP configuration.

Answer (score 5):

It's easier using "file_get_contents" with POST:

```
$postdata = http_build_query( [
    'secret'   => YOUR_SECRET_KEY,
    'response' => $_POST[ 'g-recaptcha-response' ]
] );

$opts = [
    'http' => [
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    ]
];

$context  = stream_context_create( $opts );

$result = file_get_contents(
    'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context
);

$check = json_decode( $result );
if( $check->success ) {
    echo "validate";
} else {
    echo "wrong recaptcha";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

usually I will do something like this

```
public static function validateRecaptcha($recaptcha)
{
  $dataArr = [

    'secret' => 'secret_key',
    'response' => $recaptcha,
    'remoteip'=> $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] //optional field

  ];

  $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

  try
  {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($dataArr));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    //get error code
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($responseCode >= 400) 
    {
      throw new Exception ("Response error code: {$responseCode}");
    }

    $response = json_decode($response, true);        

    if ($response['success'] === true) 
    {
        // Success
        return 'success';
    }

    throw new Exception ($response);
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    return $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "secret=$secret&response=$response",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ),
));

$responsedata = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $responsedata;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for those who prefer to use shell_exec **curl**:

```
    $arrayku = array();
    $arrayku['secret'] = 'Your_SECRET_KEY';
    $arrayku['response'] = trim($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $dataku = http_build_query($arrayku);
    $respon_google = shell_exec('curl -s -L -X POST "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" --data "'.$dataku.'" --max-time 10 --compressed');
    $array_respon = json_decode($respon_google, true);
    if($array_respon['success']===false){
    echo 'Wrong recaptcha'; echo PHP_EOL;
        //goto wrong_captcha;
        exit;
    }
```