# How to fetch from Google's ReCaptcha without using file_get_contents?

Tags: php, recaptcha

My hosted server does not allow `file_get_contents`. How can I get server validation of reCaptcha without using that call?

```
    $recaptcha_secret = "";
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);


    if ($responseKeys["success"]==true) {
```

Comment: is curl extension is loaded?

Comment: Curl extension is loaded on the remote server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL Recaptcha not working PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354633/curl-recaptcha-not-working-php)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the official reCAPTCHA class, provided by Google, it uses cURL and is easy to work with: https://github.com/google/recaptcha